# Integrating an already build PHP mvc website to wordpress

Tags: php, model-view-controller, wordpress, integrate

I have made a website with php/mysql that is using the mvc architecture. I wish to transfer all these stuff into wordpress. How do I go on doing that?
I saw WP MVP plugin but cant figure out how it is working.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize the original question was asked almost a year ago. But since I had ran into the same issue in the past, and found a very easy solution, I thought I'd post it for those that come across this.

What I use for MVC in WordPress is [RokkoMVC](http://code.google.com/p/rokko-mvc-for-wordpress/), which is not a plugin, but rather integrates directly with your theme. You can use it to better manage AJAX requests (using MVC instead of global functions in functions.php), as well as divide your code and use it through out your theme. I've found it to be a very easy and painless way to port code over from CakePHP right into WordPress.